# how to label topics automatically when training a classifier

Tags: classification

need some ideas on how to label topics automatically when training a classifier. My data set is abt 50000 texts & need to assign pre-defined topics each of them, is there any to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you could do this automatically, why would you need your classifier then?

So the answer is: there is no automatic way if you really want to generate ground-truth data.

You should look for previosly prepared, labeled data sets if possible. Otherwise you will be labeling all data by hand, sorry.

Comment: Any heuristics to make the task simpler ?

Answer (score 0):

You need some training data for your classifier, is this what you mean?

I actually ran into the same problem recently, so what I ended up doing was I got a simple listing of categories and subcategories, I iterated on those and tried to extract a wikipedia article for each one automatically.

For the category taxonomy itself, take a look at http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/, there's a categories.txt file, which you can strip down to the number of levels you want. (I used two levels, so categories and immediate subcategories only)

For article extraction, you can use [Goose](https://github.com/jiminoc/goose/wiki), it's a very easy to use Python library that pulls HTML of a document and strips the main article body out of it.

Since I ran into exactly the same thing, I created a little script to do all of this, check it out [here](https://github.com/yebrahim/tagger_trainer).